# Registro Repetidos en una tabla con Scroll infinito

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Tengo implementada una tabla con scroll infinito en HTML con jquery, php, mysql.

La consulta de los registros se hacen correctamente. En php, se manejan bien los intervalos de las consultas con la cláusula LIMIT de mysql. Y en cada respuesta, se actualizan las variables que controlan esos limites de consultas. Esa parte funciona bien al hacer el scroll.

El problema reside en que, por cada registro, el usuario puede realizar una acción por ejemplo de "activar" o "inactivar". Bien ese atributo como tal, es tomado en cuenta en la consulta para el Scroll infinito. Por lo que al realizar scroll se ve alterados la siguiente consulta, ya que ese registro no forma parte de la consulta.

Gracias de antemano.

EDIT: En pruebas realizadas, se salta la cantidad de registros así como el usuario haya cambiado en la siguiente consulta.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Sin nada de código es complicado resolver tu problema...

Comment: Si te entiendo bien, tu scroll determina qué filas traerse desde el backend, y desde el backend te manda las filas activas que correspondan a la posición de tu scroll. El hecho de desactivar filas rio arriba provoca que en el siguiente llamado al backend la respuesta esté desplazada en tantas filas como antes se desactivaron.  Para ayudarte es necesario ver algo de tu código, más que nada entender cómo haces la relación "posición del scroll => posición de la fila"

Comment: Gracias por su ayuda, ya lo he solucionado. La respuesta algoritmicamente fue mas sencilla de lo que esperaba. Simplemente tenia que detectar cuantas filas habían sido desactivadas y restarle esa cantidad al offset ( indice ) , antes de hacer el llamado nuevamente a la consulta.